# Search method for different columns

Tags: c#, linq, properties, entity-framework-core

I have `Form` with `ComboBox` and `TextBox`. The first contains the column names, and the second contains the text to search for. As a source, `ComboBox` takes `ListTypeSearch` from `ItemSearch` elements. The `Search()` method is called in the processing of pressing the `Search` button.

If give the column a name like this, nothing will be found

```
EF.Functions.Like(item.Value, ...); // Value = "FullName"
```

If specify a column from the model, the search works

```
EF.Functions.Like(w.FullName, ...);
```

Is it possible to replace the column that should be searched within the same `Search()` method?

```
ListTypeSearch.Add(new ItemSearch { Value = "FullName", Display = "some text" });
ListTypeSearch.Add(new ItemSearch { Value = "PassportSeries", Display = "some text" });
ListTypeSearch.Add(new ItemSearch { Value = "PassportNumber", Display = "some text" });

public class ItemSearch
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
}

internal List<WorkerTableRow> Search(ItemSearch item, string text)
{
    try
    {
        Found = new List<WorkerTableRow>();
        using (ModelContext model = new ModelContext())
        {
            Found = (from w in model.Workers
                     where EF.Functions.Like(w.FullName, // this code
                                             String.Format("%{0}%", text))
                     select new WorkerTableRow
                     {
                         ...
                     })
                     .ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ... }

    return Found;
}
```

**Update**

Now I did like this. It's works. Can this be simplified?

```
where EF.Functions.Like(w.GetProperty(item.Value), 
                        String.Format("%{0}%", text))


public partial class Workers
{
    ...

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string PassportSeries { get; set; }
    public string PassportNumber { get; set; }

    public string GetProperty(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "FullName":
                return FullName;
            case "PassportSeries":
                return PassportSeries;
            case "PassportNumber":
                return PassportNumber;
            default:
                return string.Empty;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try This: where EF.Functions.Contains(w.FullName,text)

Comment: `w.FullName.Contains(text)` should do the same thing, unless you have other wildcards included in `text`.

Comment: As for substituting the search column you could include a `Expression<Func<Worker, bool>> predicate` and then pass `w => w.FullName.Contains(text)` or `w => w.SomeOtherColumn.Contains(test)`.  and use it like this `model.Workers.Where(predicate)`

Comment: @juharr  But "FullName" is one from some variants. I need to change it.

Comment: Answer [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1003027/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According other [answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1003995/339653). If uses `Like(w.GetProperty(item.Value), ...)`, the request is executed on the client, not on the server. To send the entire request to the server, you can do the following:

```
List<WorkerTableRow> Search(ItemSearch item, string text)
{
    string pattern = string.Format("%{0}%", text);

    using (var model = new ModelContext())
    {
        IQueryable<Worker> query = model.Workers;

        if (item.Value == "FullName")
            query = query.Where(w => EF.Functions.Like(w.FullName, pattern));

        if (item.Value == "PassportSeries")
            query = query.Where(w => EF.Functions.Like(w.PassportSeries, pattern));

        if (item.Value == "PassportNumber")
            query = query.Where(w => EF.Functions.Like(w.PassportNumber, pattern));

        return query.Select(w => new WorkerTableRow { ... }).ToList();
    }
}
```